# UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular2@2.0.0-beta.14

Tags: npm, angular

I've installed npm package and I noticed this console log:

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular2@2.0.0-beta.14

npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN angular2-modal@0.1.4 requires a peer of angular2@2.0.0-beta.15 but none was installed.
npm WARN ng2-bootstrap@1.0.15 requires a peer of angular2@2.0.0-beta.16 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

What does that mean?

I tried to npm install angular2, but the output is same.

package.json depencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@angular2-material/progress-circle": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@angular2-material/radio": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.14",
    "angular2-modal": "^0.1.3",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.11",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.5.1",
    "ng2-material": "^0.3.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "zone.js": "0.6.6",
    "socket.io":"1.4.5"
```

Comment: It means that one or more of the dependencies you have in your package are only compatible with angular angular2@2.0.0-beta.14 or maybe higher. What version does it list in your package.json?

Comment: added my package.json depencies to my question

Comment: try doing npm uninstall angular2 follwed by npm cache clear and npm install angular2.

Comment: Sorry, I think I've missed some more information, I get this WARN console logs, as updated in my question

Comment: Why not change (update, actually) angular2 version to `2.0.0-beta.17`?

Comment: I assumed using `npm install` angular2 update it.. anyway, now it's `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY angular2@2.0.0-beta.17`

Comment: Did those warnings go away, at least?

Comment: put it to the highest version that it says it's missing.

Comment: @acdcjunior Worse, now I get more warns `npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2@2.0.0-beta.17 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.6.12 but none was installed.`

Comment: @TheUnreal: update package.json and set rxjs to 5.0.0-beta.6.

Answer (score -1):

This seemed to have worked for me:

```
npm install --save rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12
```